# a way to access different folders in different locations by one click

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, user-folders

I have different folders in all drives which contain same data.

I can't store all of it in the same folder or drive.

I am wondering if there's a way I can access all of those locations in a single click or in a single virtual folder or drive without all of them being there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which *version* of Windows you use. Starting with Windows 7, [**Libraries**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee449413(v=ws.10).aspx) were added, which provide "a single aggregated view of multiple folders." Your description, "virtual folder", describes them well. Libraries are links to multiple folders and do not duplicate the contents.

The default libraries are Documents, Music, Pictures, and Videos, but you can easily add a Library for another type.

If you have Windows 8 or 10, [you may need to make the Libraries visible in Windows Explorer.](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/introducing-windows-81-how-get-back-libraries-file-explorer)

Comment: i know about libraries and its windows 8.1 which i'm using but i need to view all inside files and folders in one place but in libbraries they are shown as somewhat like links and if i wanted that i would have just made shortcuts